# Disable "Take Photo" / "Take Video" on mobile for <input type="file">

Tags: iphone, file, input, mobile, file-upload

I'm using dropzone to upload media files, but this question can be simplified for just `<input type="file">`: on mobile when clicking on the input it shows three options: "Photo Library", "Take Photo", "Browse". I need to hide or disable the `"Take Photo"` option so users can only choose their files from library. Is there a way to do so?